# How to Raise a validation error if a field is empty odoo 12?

Tags: odoo

What I have tried to do is that if the specialist_name is empty, I have to raise a Validation Error. But it is not working. What am I doing wrong? My python code is below:

```py
specialist_name = fields.Many2one(
    'res.partner',domain=[('is_specialist','=',True)],string="Specialist")

@api.constrains('specialist_name')
def _onchange_value(self):
    if self.specialist_name == False:
        raise ValidationError(_('Only The Specialist Has The Provision To Create'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`specialist_name` is a `Many2one` field, and the value of such a field is a recordset of size 0 (no record) or 1 (a single record).

The `self.specialist_name == False` expression will be always evaluated to `False` and the body of if statement will never be executed.

Empty records are evaluated to False in a boolean context such as if or while statements, try to use:

```py
if not self.specialist_name:
```

***Edit:***

> `@constrains` will be triggered only if the declared fields in the decorated method are included in the `create` or `write` call. It implies that fields not present in a view will not trigger a call during record creation. An override of `create` is necessary to make sure a constraint will always be triggered (e.g. to test the absence of value).

If you override the `create` or `write` method, you will find that `specialist_name` key is not present in values and if you add the specialist name to values the constraint will work.

When we set a read-only field, we prevent the user from modifying it and handle its value in the background. We do not need to warn the user since the value of the field can't be changed from the UI.

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge,It is good learning lessons from you.

Comment: It works,But when i gave the field into readonly as <field name="specialist_name" readonly='1'/> not raising the validation.

Comment: Because specialist name is not included in `create` or `write` call. Check my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your time and lesson again.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a more simpler solution and making the field required?

There are broadly speaking two positions/areas to do it.

1. on views, which will give you some flexibility on implemented processes (maybe there will be cases where you don't want to have it required)

```xml
<field name="my_field" required="1" />
```

2. on field declaration

```py
my_field = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="my.comodel", required=True)
```